# Contextmenu not working when the main Thread is busy?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an app in which i am trying to update the main thread from another thread every second. There is a list view in the main thread and i modify the each view of the list every 1 second and post the result to the main thread. Now the problem is that every 1 second the main thread starts to run the changing codes so that makes the long click action disabled. So i can't use the context menu for the items of the List View. So if you could help me I would be so grateful...

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
          try {

                  for(int i=0;i<maxNumberOfDownloads;i++)
                {
                    if(i<ActiveDownload)
                    {
                        calculateDownloadDetails(i);
                    }
                }  

          } finally {
               // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
               // your update method throws an exception
               progressBarList.setAdapter(new DownloadingCustomAdapter(context,progressbarListDetails,ActiveDownload));
               mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval); 
               /*
                * The handler class is the only way to interact with the main UI, so when we want to update 
                * Something from the UI, we have to send the data to the main thread which is the MainActivity
                * postDelayed method adds the runnable mStatusChecker to the message queue every mInterval time
                */
          }
    }
```

Comment: did you use ArrayAdapter for changing your list?

Comment: yes . the handler actually sets the adapter every second to the list view

Comment: @AminYosefi you don't need to do that, you can simply edit the items or add/remove items and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: Thanks @Titus. that was what i meant to say.

Comment: i just added the code, as you can see in the runnable i first change data by calling the calculateDownloadDetails(i) and then refresh the list view by refreshing the progressbarlist[]. how can i modify the codes above?